# Starting rails server for different apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I am working on two different rails apps (app_one, app_two), how does the rails server work when I switch from working on app_one to working on app_two? Does app_two show up in a different port? When I go to localhost:3000 it keeps showing app_one. I tried closing all of my terminals and then rebooting the rails server from the app_two root directory, but I still get app_one at localhost:3000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When starting your server you can specify a port:

```
rails s -p 3000 #rails 3 server starting on port 3000 (default)
rails s -p 3001 #rails 3 server starting on port 3001
```

or for rails 2:

```
script/server -p 3000
script/server -p 3001
```

Then you can switch between the two at will